# firebase.d.ts iOS works but Android freezes

Tags: cordova, angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am using Ionic 2 building on Mac.

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

I have an app I have been developing. When I build the app via Xcode for iOS, everything works fine.

But when I try build it for Android, it generates the `android-debug.apk` file, but if I try run this on an emulator (Android Studio) or my Android phone, it seems to load but then freeze.

I have 3 pages. It loads the initial page, I can navigate to the second page, but as soon as I try navigate to the third page, the navigation freezes. This only occurs in Android.

As a result I think there may be a problem with my third page that is causing the navigation to break.

If anyone has any suggestions, or can suggest how I can debug this, I would appreciate your help.

This is the third page (the initial alert in the constructor doesn't get invoked):

**login.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, Platform, Loading, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FirebaseAuth, AuthProviders, FirebaseAuthState } from 'angularfire2';
import { JobModel } from '../model/jobModel';
import { PersonModel } from '../model/personModel';
import { UtilityService } from '../utils/utilityService';
import { PersonService } from '../service/personService';
import { LoginEmailPage } from '../loginemail/loginemail';
import { PersonPage } from '../person/person';
import { PersonUserService } from '../person/personUserService';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  public jobModel: JobModel;
  public personModel: PersonModel;
  public fireAuth: firebase.auth.Auth;
  public utilityService: UtilityService = null;
  public loading: Loading = null;
  public authState: FirebaseAuthState = null;

  constructor( @Inject(forwardRef(() => UtilityService)) utilityService, public nav: NavController, public auth: FirebaseAuth, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public personService: PersonService, public platform: Platform, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public personUserService: PersonUserService) {
    alert('login.ts constructor');
    this.fireAuth = firebase.auth();
    this.utilityService = utilityService;
    this.utilityService.logout(this.auth, this.fireAuth);
    this.auth.subscribe((authState: FirebaseAuthState) => {
      this.authState = authState;
    });
  }

  setUpUser(firebaseAuthState: FirebaseAuthState, provider_id: number): Promise<PersonModel> {
    return new Promise<PersonModel>((resolve) => {
      let provider: AuthProviders = firebaseAuthState.provider;
      if (!provider) {
        provider = provider_id;
      }
      this.personService.getPersonByUidAndProvider(window.localStorage.getItem('uid'), provider).then((personModel: PersonModel) => {
        if (personModel && personModel.id) {
          this.personModel = personModel;
          this.personModel.provider = provider;
          if (!this.personModel || !this.personModel.uid) {
            this.fireAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user: firebase.User) => {
              if (user) {
                this.newPerson(user, firebaseAuthState, provider_id).then((data: PersonModel) => {
                  this.personModel = data;
                  resolve(this.personModel);
                });
              }
            });
          } else {
            this.personModel.avatarFirebase = window.localStorage.getItem('photoURL');
            this.personModel.lastAccessDate = new Date().getTime();
            let user: firebase.User = this.fireAuth.currentUser;
            if (!user) {
              let loginPromise: Promise<PersonModel> = this.utilityService.login(this.personModel, this.authState.auth, this.nav, this.auth, this.fireAuth, false);
              if (loginPromise) {
                loginPromise.then((person: PersonModel) => {
                  resolve(person);
                });
              } else {
                resolve(null);
              }
            } else {
              let loginPromise: Promise<PersonModel> = this.utilityService.login(this.personModel, user, this.nav, this.auth, this.fireAuth, false);
              if (loginPromise) {
                loginPromise.then((person: PersonModel) => {
                  resolve(person);
                });
              } else {
                resolve(null);
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          let user: firebase.User = this.fireAuth.currentUser;
          if (this.authState && this.authState.auth) {
            this.newPerson(this.authState.auth, firebaseAuthState, provider_id).then((personData: PersonModel) => {
              this.personModel = personData;
              resolve(this.personModel);
            });
          } else if (user) {
            this.newPerson(user, firebaseAuthState, provider_id).then((personData: PersonModel) => {
              this.personModel = personData;
              resolve(this.personModel);
            });
          } else {
            this.doAlert('Logging into Firebase unsuccessful');
            console.info('Logging into Firebase unsuccessful', this.authState, user);
          }
        }
      }, (error) => {
        console.error('Error getting personModel for uid: ' + window.localStorage.getItem('uid'), error);
      });
    });
  }

  newPerson(user: firebase.User, firebaseAuthState: FirebaseAuthState, provider_id: number): Promise<PersonModel> {
    return new Promise<PersonModel>(resolve => {
      this.personModel = new PersonModel();
      if (user && user.email) {
        this.personModel.emailAddress = user.email;
      } else if (firebaseAuthState && firebaseAuthState.auth && firebaseAuthState.auth.email) {
        this.personModel.emailAddress = firebaseAuthState.auth.email;
      } else if (this.fireAuth && this.fireAuth.currentUser && this.fireAuth.currentUser.email) {
        this.personModel.emailAddress = this.fireAuth.currentUser.email;
      } else {
        console.error('Firebase current user is null, so cannot get email address and cannot save user to RESTful Service.', this.fireAuth);
      }
      this.personModel.uid = window.localStorage.getItem('uid');
      this.personModel.displayName = window.localStorage.getItem('displayName');
      this.personModel.avatarFirebase = window.localStorage.getItem('photoURL');
      this.personModel.provider = firebaseAuthState.provider;
      this.personModel.lastAccessDate = new Date().getTime();
      if (!this.personModel.provider) {
        this.personModel.provider = provider_id;
      }
      if (this.personModel.emailAddress) {
        this.utilityService.getPersonLocations(this.personModel).then((person: PersonModel) => {
          return this.savePerson(person, user).then((person: PersonModel) => {
            resolve(person);
          });
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.info('Saving person, but location not found');
          return this.savePerson(this.personModel, user).then((person: PersonModel) => {
            resolve(person);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }

  savePerson(personModel: PersonModel, user: firebase.User): Promise<PersonModel> {
    return new Promise<PersonModel>(resolve => {
      this.personModel = personModel;
      this.personService.savePerson(this.personModel).then((personModel: PersonModel) => {
        this.utilityService.login(personModel, user, this.nav, this.auth, this.fireAuth, true).then((person: PersonModel) => {
          resolve(person);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  signIn(firebaseAuthState: FirebaseAuthState, provider_id: number) {
    let emailVerified: boolean = false;
    let user: firebase.User = this.fireAuth.currentUser;
    if (user) {
      if (user.emailVerified) {
        emailVerified = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (firebaseAuthState.auth && firebaseAuthState.auth.emailVerified) {
        emailVerified = true;
      }
    }
    if (firebaseAuthState && firebaseAuthState.uid) {
      this.setUpUser(firebaseAuthState, provider_id).then((personModel: PersonModel) => {
        if (personModel && emailVerified) {
          this.nav.setRoot(PersonPage, {
            personModel: personModel,
            fromLogin: true
          }).then(() => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
          });
        }
      });
    }
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
    }, 6000);
  }

  // sanityCheck(firebaseAuthState: FirebaseAuthState): void {
  //   if (firebaseAuthState && firebaseAuthState.auth && !firebaseAuthState.auth.emailVerified) {
  //     this.personService.getPersonByUid(firebaseAuthState.uid).then((personModel: any) => {
  //       if (!personModel) {
  //         console.error('RDS PersonModel does not exist for Firebase User ', personModel, firebaseAuthState);
  //         firebaseAuthState.auth.delete().then(() => {
  //           console.info('Firebase User deleted', firebaseAuthState);
  //         });
  //       } else if (personModel.ok === false) {
  //         console.error('RDS PersonModel does not exist for Firebase User ', personModel, firebaseAuthState);
  //         firebaseAuthState.auth.delete().then(() => {
  //           console.info('Firebase User deleted', firebaseAuthState);
  //         });
  //       }
  //     }).catch((error) => {
  //       console.error('RDS PersonModel does not exist for Firebase User ', firebaseAuthState);
  //       firebaseAuthState.auth.delete().then(() => {
  //         console.info('Firebase User deleted', firebaseAuthState);
  //       });
  //     });
  //   }
  // }

  loginGoogle(): void {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...'
    });
    this.loading.present();
    this.personUserService.init(this.nav, this.personModel, null, this.loading);
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.personUserService.loginGoogleCordova().then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
          this.signIn(data, AuthProviders.Google);
        });
      });
    } else {
      this.personUserService.loginGoogleBrowser().then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
        this.signIn(data, AuthProviders.Google);
      });
    }
  }

  loginFacebook(): void {
    alert('login.ts loginFacebook');
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...'
    });
//    this.loading.present();
    this.personUserService.init(this.nav, this.personModel, null, this.loading);
    alert('login.ts loginFacebook just initialised personUserService');
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    alert('login.ts loginFacebook cordova');
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    alert('login.ts loginFacebook ready');
        this.personUserService.loginFacebookCordova().then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
    alert('login.ts loginFacebook loginFacebookCordova done');
          this.signIn(data, AuthProviders.Facebook);
        });
      });
    } else {
    alert('login.ts loginFacebook not cordova');
      this.personUserService.loginFacebookBrowser().then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
    alert('login.ts loginFacebook loginFacebookBrowser done');
        this.signIn(data, AuthProviders.Facebook);
      });
    }
  }

  loginEmail() {
    this.nav.push(LoginEmailPage);
  }

  doAlert(msg: string) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Login',
      subTitle: msg,
      buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    alert.present();
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Found what is causing it to crash, but I don't know why.

In the constructor:

```
alert('personUserService.ts constructor');
alert('personUserService.ts constructor firebase = '+firebase);
    this.fireAuth = firebase.auth();
alert('personUserService.ts constructor this.fireAuth = '+this.fireAuth);
    this.auth.subscribe((authState: FirebaseAuthState) => {
        this.authState = authState;
    });
```

The first alert gets invoked, and then it freezes. This means that the `firebase` object is causing it to freeze.

This works in `iOS`, so not sure why it does not in `Android`.

`firebase` is a namespace referencing `firebase.d.ts`  in the `node_modules/firebase/server-auth-node/` folder.

Comment: You can debug or pin point the problem by placing alert in different places in app.ts where the app starts. Also, see if everything is working fine at `platform.ready()`.

Comment: I can add alerts thanks you. I don't know how to add debug points in Android Studio. If I try debug in Android Studio, I get: `Cannot start compilation: the output path is not specified for module "myapp". Specify the output path in Configure Project.`

Comment: I cannot help you regarding Android studio debugging. Not done myself ever. Alert seems to work for me. Also, check `platform.ready()`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try alert statements. p.s. The android build returns 404 Not Found for all requests to a RESTful Service where the iOS build gets a result returned too.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following, and all my issues went away:

1) `ionic platform rm android`
2) `ionic platform add android`